# Dedicated bluemix very slow

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

Since last week, dedicated Bluemix is working very slow and sometimes throws a timeout on conection with dashDB, so i wanted to ask if is it a problem with bluemix in general, or we have an issue with our dashDB?

Thanks.

Comment: There has been some maintenance performed on Db2 and Db2 Warehouse services over the last few weeks. Any change in behavior might be attributed to that maintenance. I am not sure which Db2 service you are using. See the IBM Cloud platform page for information: https://console.bluemix.net/status?tags=platform,runtimes,services,ibm:yp:us-south,ibm:yp:eu-gb,ibm:yp:eu-de,ibm:yp:au-syd,experimental_services,ibm:yp:us-east&view=n:m

Comment: I would also recommend that you open a Support ticket so that the IBM Cloud Support engineers can look specifically at your environment and determine exactly why you are experiencing the slow down. For information on submitting a ticket, see: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/howtogetsupport.html#getting-customer-support